# Can cyclic quadrilateral be a parallelogram $?$

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

**Question:** a) Can cyclic quadrilateral be a parallelogram $?$

b) Can a parallelogram be cyclic $?$

**Solution:** a) Cyclic quadrilateral can be a rectangle or square.

They are also parallelogram.

So cyclic quadrilateral can be parallelogram

b) parallelogram is cyclic when it is rectangle.

So parallelogram can be cyclic.

Am I right $?$

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: But my teacher said that parallelogram can be be cyclic but cyclic quadrilateral can not be parallelogram

Comment: A square is both...

Comment: @rst Your teacher is right: an isosceles trapezoid is always cyclic, yet it clearly is not a parallelogram. I think the difference here is between "can be" and "must be".

Comment: But @Joanpemo, the situation is symmetrical: some, but not all, parallelograms are cyclic; and some, but not all, cyclic quadrilaterals are parallelograms. So whatever your interpretation of "can not be", the teacher's alleged statement is false one way or the other.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you. I know, it is only that the asker's redaction may be inaccurate or be failing under translation. I am guessing the asker's teacher said "A cyclic quadrilateral not necessarily is a parallelogram" or some similar version of this.

Answer (score 2):

One picture is worth a thousand words

[image: picture]

**Square $\subset$ Rectangle $\subset($Parallelogram $\cap$ Cyclic quadrilateral$)$**

Comment: Then why not include it in your answer?

Comment: Complex quadrilaterals can also be cyclic.  Think of a rectangle but instead of all four sides you render two opposite sides plus the diagonals.